# get monthwise row count from datewise data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have two tables:

```
 table 1.a
    id--entry_date-amount
============================
    2---2016-04-14--$400
    3---2016-04-14--$400
    4----2017-07-14--$200
    5---2017-07-14--$500
    6---2017-05-14--$600
    7----2017-06-18--$100

    table 2.b
    id--entry_date
===========================
    2---2016-04-14--$230
    3---2016-04-14--$230
    4----2017-07-14--$567
    5---2017-07-14--$600
    6---2017-05-14--$560
    7----2017-06-18--$90
    8---2016-04-14--$100
```

from the two tables how can i get count with montwise
my desired result:

```
month_name--total(count form table a)--total(count form table b)--amount(table a)--amount(table b)
========================================================
April,16-----------2-------------------3---$800-$500
May,17-----------1-------------------1 --$600--$700
June,17-----------2-------------------2--$100--$800
July,17-----------2-------------------2---$700-$400
```

this is the demo data. 
I want to show data from two tables in a single query month wise.
How can i do this?

I tried:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(r.entry_date),r.a_total FROM( 
SELECT
IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(tr.id) AS amount FROM a AS tr WHERE MONTH(tr.entry_date)=MONTH(t.entry_date)),0) AS a_total
,t.entry_date

FROM(SELECT tr.id,tr.entry_date
 FROM a AS tr
 WHERE DATE(tr.entry_date) BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-30') t

   GROUP BY MONTH(t.entry_date)) r
```

But takes 58 seconds for simple query. How can i make this in a simple query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the counts and sum from each table individually, then use `UNION` to combine the two result sets into one result set. Something like this :

```
SELECT Month_name,
  SUM(aCount) AS aCount,
  SUM(bCount) AS bCount,
  SUM(aAmount) AS aAmount,
  SUM(bAmount) AS bAmount
FROM
(
  SELECT  
    MONTHNAME(a.entry_date) AS Month_name,
    COUNT(a.id) AS aCount,
    0 AS bCount,
    SUM(a.amount) AS aAmount,
    0 AS bAmount
  FROM a
  GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.entry_date)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  
    MONTHNAME(b.entry_date) AS Month_name,
    0 AS aCount,
    COUNT(b.id) AS bCount,
    0 AS aAmount,
    SUM(b.amount) AS bAmount
  FROM b
  GROUP BY MONTHNAME(b.entry_date)
) AS t
GROUP BY Month_Name;
```

[**live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f64864/7)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can it be done using sub query? which one is bettet? union or sub query?

Comment: @Fawel Yes It can be done with a subquery and a join. But this is better since there is no relation between the two tables.

Comment: Then how can get total of all column as last row? Suppose in month_column's last row will be 'Total', 'aCount's last row 6, .... like that. I am now using union all to get that type of result

Answer (score 0):

user9131497 has a good design for the big picture.  However, I would suggest stuff like this for handling the dates:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(entry_date, "%M,%y") AS 'Month',
        COUNT(*) AS 'aCount'
    FROM a
    GROUP BY LEFT(entry_date, 7)  -- eg, "2017-03"
```

Try that to see what I mean.

Note that this will work beyond a year.  Or did you need January values from all years to be combined?? -- That's what your solution and user9131497's will do.  Mine keeps them separate.